# Android WebView Not Displaying Certain Websites

Tags: android

Trying to create an Android app for my site which can simply display the webpage in the Android app.

I have the following code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        /*WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); Works with and without this commented part*/
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.javatpoint.com/");

    }
}
```

The above is working fine and displays the 'https://www.javatpoint.com/' webpage correctly in the Android app.

However, the moment I change the "`mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.javatpoint.com/");`" to my own test website "`mywebview.loadUrl("https://example.com/j2f6/xaph1.html");`" , it displays a blank screen on the emulator as well as the connected mobile app.

I have granted all the necessary permissions in the manifest.xml file, like,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And since it is working for 'https://www.javatpoint.com/' but not for my site 'https://example.com/j2f6/xaph1.html', I assume there is some configuration issue??

**Interesting Observation:**

When I use "`mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.Javatpoint.com/");`", it opens the webpage in the Android app itself. However, when I use "`mywebview.loadUrl("https://Javatpoint.com/");`" (without www), it launches the app, keeps the app screen blank, and opens the Javatpoint.com site in the default browser of the Android mobile.

Same is happening with "`mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/");`" and "mywebview.loadUrl("https://w3schools.com/");". The former opens in app, the latter starts the default browser and opens in that.

But for my site https://example.com/j2f6/xaph1.html, its neither opening in the app, nor is it triggering the browser (with or without www.)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make this link from `https://pricepurple.com/j4f/xaph1.html` to `https://www.pricepurple.com/j4f/xaph1.html`. You may be missing a `www`.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setWebChromeClient to enable javascript in your WebView. But don't worry, you can use both setWebChromeClient and setWebViewClient in the same time. Just like in official docs:

```
  // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
  // browser app does.
  getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

  webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

  final Activity activity = this;
  webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
      // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different      scales.
      // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
      activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
    }
  });
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String      description, String failingUrl) {
      Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description,      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });

  webview.loadUrl("https://pricepurple.com/j4f/xaph1.html");
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Thanks @avihaiB, but this ain't working. Throwing error that 'This app has stopped working' even for the first URL (with which it was working earlier)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
uncomment those websetting lines and
after this line `setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`
write `setDomStorageEnabled(true)`

like this
`webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)`

Comment: Thanks @Nomankhanbhai. But unfortunately, its Not working. It is really surprising that even with all these edits, the 'javatpoint.com' site is opening fine, but my site just does not show up.

Comment: Your site is loading in my webview properly. 
Inside AndroidManifest -> application tag.
you can try this as well ```android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"```
or you can try another device and check wether site is loading or not. @Aquaholic

Comment: unfortunately, still not working. Have also updated the q with some more observations (under the head "Interesting Observation". If that can provide some pointers to make it work.